# A better way in React to update a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm building a simple shopping cart for a site and have been working on the `add to cart`action. While I have ti working I feel there is probably a simple more elegant way of doing it.

This is the starting state:

```
start_state = {
  inventory: [
   {sku: "product_1", price: 600, name: "Product 1"},
   {sku: "product_2", price: 800, name: "Product 2"}
  ],
  cart: []
}
```

And this is the desired end state:

```
start_state = {
  inventory: [
   {sku: "product_1", price: 600, name: "Product 1"},
   {sku: "product_2", price: 800, name: "Product 2"}
  ],
  cart: [
   {sku: "product_1", quantity: 2},
   {sku: "product_2", quantity: 1}
  ]
}
```

And this is the function Im triggering to take it from the initial state to new final_state, the `sku` argument is the item from the state that is passed in when the action is called:

```
addToCart: function (sku) {
  let currentCart = this.state.cart
  let itemInCart = _.findIndex(currentCart, ['sku', sku])

  let newItem = { sku: sku }
  if (itemInCart !== -1) {
    let newQuantity = currentCart[itemInCart].quantity
    newItem.quantity = newQuantity + 1
  } else {
    newItem.quantity = 1
  }

  let filteredCart = _.filter(currentCart, (item) => { return item.sku !== sku })
  let newCart = _.concat(filteredCart, newItem)

  this.setState({cart: newCart})
},
```

Comment: are you using es6?

Comment: Yes using Babel to transpile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ES6, you can use some of its new features like `findIndex` and `Object.assign` to achieve what you want.

```
addToCart: function(product) {
        let index = this.state.cart.findIndex((x) => x.sku === product.sku);
        if(index === -1) {
          let newProduct = {sku: product.sku, quantity:1}
            this.setState({cart : this.state.cart.concat([newProduct])})
        }
        else {
          let newCart = Object.assign([], this.state.cart);
          newCart[index].quantity = newCart[index].quantity+1;
          this.setState({cart: newCart});
        }
}
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/638/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is better:

```
function getCardWithIncItem(currentCart, itemInCart) {
    return [
        ...currentCart.slice(0, itemInCart),
        Object.assign({}, currentCart[itemInCart], {
            quantity: currentCart[itemInCart].quantity + 1,
        }),
        ...currentCart.slice(itemInCart + 1),
    ];
}

function getCardWithNewItem(currentCart, sku) {
    return [
        ...currentCart, {
            sku: sku,
            quantity: 1,
        }
    ];
}

const currentCart = this.state.cart;
const itemInCart = _.findIndex(currentCart, ['sku', sku]);
const newCart = (itemInCart !== -1)
    ? getCardWithIncItem(currentCart, itemInCart)
    : getCardWithIncItem(currentCart, sku);
this.setState({
    cart: newCart,
})
```